# Change background color for different DIV's in PHP/SQL output

Tags: php, mysql, html, background-color

I'm trying to form my PHP/MySQL output in a 'Word-like' table format: one row is background color X, the next is bg color Y, then X again, then Y, etc.

To do this I've come up with a solution, but I'm guessing it's not really the neatest or cleanest way to do it. Check out my solution. I'm looking forward to your ideas/input!

```
$selectdoc = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE docid = '" . $_GET['docid'] . "' LIMIT 10";
$queryselectdoc = mysql_query($selectdoc);

$colorindicator = 1;

while($dbdoc = mysql_fetch_object($queryselectdoc)) {

   $title = "$dbdoc->title";

   $colorindicator = $colorindicator+1;

     if ( $i&1 )
      {
        echo "<div id=\"even\">My BG color is the one based on EVEN!</div>";
      }
     else
      {
        echo "<div id=\"odd\">My BG color is the one based on ODD!</div>";
      }

 }
```

Comment: You're using HTML IDs for things that there are going to be mroe than one of.  This goes against the HTML specs, they state that you can only use a given ID once.  Fortunately the solution is simple, use class instead.  You might be interested in http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/zebra-striping-tables-with-css3/ which describes how to do zebra striping with pure CSS. Also, you could abbreviate $colorindicator = $colorindicator+1 to $colorindicator++

Comment: Bear in mind nth-child will not work on IE8 and earlier. It is only introduced in IE9, so if you want it to work in other versions of IE you need to implement javascript similar to you have above.

Comment: Only tried it in Chrome/FF yet, but this kinda kills the whole thing. Thanks @anothershrubery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS pseudo classes `:nth-child` using a list or a table or something

Try using a list like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7unrQ/) :-)

Comment: Really like this solution! Easy and simple. Of course it's also better to use a List instead of a Div. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thank you :-) I myself discovered the `:nth-child()` class recently. A wonderful find I say - saves having to do the silly `if()` in PHP or a ternary operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter:

```
echo ((++$colorindicator % 2)==1) ? "<div id=\"odd\">" : "<div id=\"even\">";
echo "contents</div>";
```

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for multiple elements. Use `class`.

Comment: Quite. Also, take a look at my answer - using CSS is cleaner than messing around with ternary operators and different classes :-)